# simple pointcloud subscriber

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and I stuck in a beginner problem. I already did the ROS Tutorials where I wrote a subscriber but it doesn't explain my problem. I wanna write a simple subscriber in C++ for the kinect (topic => /camera/depth_registered/points). My code looks like the following:

void pcdCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg)
{

ROS_INFO("pointcloud recieved");

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "pcdlistener");

ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, pcdCallback);

ros::spin();

return 0;

}

My Problem is now that the compiling produces the following failure:

/home/ronny/ros/pkgs/subscriber_pcd/src/pcdsubscriber.cpp:7: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘sensor_msgs’ with no type

would be great to get a hint or solution.

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12139/simple-pointcloud-subscriber/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2011-11-29**:
First of all, welcome to ROS! About your question: Did you forget this: #include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>? it would be helpful for us if you posted the complete code (with #includes and all that). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys,

I solved the problem on my own. It happened, what had to happen...
After I looked over an hour for the failure I posted the question and right after that I found the solution.
I had forgotten to add the boost directories to the CMake.

rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

But thanks for your quick response and hint with the pcl_ros I will definitely have a look on that.

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to #include the appropriate header for `PointCloud2`s:

```
#include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h"
```

However, let me suggest something better: rather than subscribe to PointCloud2 objects (which are literal translations of the on-the-wire format, and somewhat hard to deal with), take a look at `pcl_ros`, and subscribe to `PointCloud<PointXYZ>` (or `PointCloud<PointXYZ>`, depending on your data); that way, all of the translation to a PCL type (and all the helpful machinery that comes with it) are done for you.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4